# why there is error in async pipe "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

i am trying to apply searching in the table through ng-bootstrap. But there is an error in the async pipe ="InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'" i have applied same as shown in ng-botstrap website.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
  
          <thead class="thead-dark">
  
            <tr>
              <th>S.No.</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Date Of Birth</th>
              <th>Contact Number</th>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Action</th>
              
            </tr>
          </thead>
  
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="  let recentDetails of user$ | async; index as i ">
              <td >{{i+1+((tableModel.Page-1)*tableModel.pageSize)}}</td>
              <td ><ngb-highlight [result]="recentDetails.name" [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight></td>
              <td ><ngb-highlight [result]="recentDetails.email" [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight></td>
              <td ><ngb-highlight [result]="recentDetails.dateOfBirth" [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight></td>
              <td ><ngb-highlight [result]="recentDetails.contactNumber" [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight></td>
              <td><img src="https://localhost:44342/Images/{{recentDetails.userImageGuid}}"></td> 
              <td> <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="editUserDetails(recentDetails.email)">Edit</button> &nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteRow(recentDetails.id,i)">Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

please help me out .
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `user$` is an array of objects rather than an observable of an array of objects. If that is the case, you can remove the `| async` and it should work regardless.

If you need the `user$` to be an observable, you will have to recheck your Typescript code. Also, if you need help with that, you should share relevant TS code snippets as well.